# HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for api url

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to update and insert with one post request but its giving error.

[image: This is the error i m facing]

This is my API code

[image: This is the asp.net core 5.0 web api code]

This the service code:

[image: This the service code]

This is the function calling code:

[image]

[This is the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzcKa.png)

[API c# model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqAWZ.png)

[Data which is been pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkItj.png)

[TraceId and request data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1562f.png)

Comment: can you add the post model?  issue is related to post model validation, are you using any validation attribute?

Comment: i have add the model screenshot now please check

Comment: add your c# model

Comment: now please check

Comment: can you expand the error section in your request result image (first image) so I can see traceId

Comment: now check please

Comment: As per the error message, it is not able to parse Percentage.

Comment: can you add request data as well?

Comment: Now please check

Comment: make Percentage Nullable by adding ? (question mark) , then try again.

Comment: didn't work @Manish

Comment: Yaa now some other error is coming, something related to DateTime Format. I just checked the latest image you have added, if you check closely all the errors are related to Json Parsing.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: now its giving error: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean

Answer (score 0):

System.Single is a single-precision floating-point number. You can use the Convert.ToInt32(), if you want to convert a boxed float to an integer.

Comment: now its giving date error

Comment: now its giving error: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean

Comment: so this means you have a couple of errors @NabeelKhan What is the latest error now?

Comment: its "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean"

Comment: hope this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/217002/ignore-json-types.html @NabeelKhan